# Managing file specific access permissions for static resources in springboot with spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security, static-files

I have sensitive models that I want to serve to a web client. I was wondering if I could have file-specific user access permissions setup with spring. I know I could just set resources to be accessible by authenticated users. Still, I also want some user whitelist for some models or have some models publically accessible. Is there a way to implement some kind of registry that can be updated containing permissions that Spring could just read from?

One solution I can think of is setting up a get handler for models and, based on model id, dynamically checking user permissions and responding with the result.